# How to get an instance UserControl from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML, I put an user control. I'd like to get that instance in initialize component in C# code.

Comment: How about naming it? (Also your question does not seem quite clear to me)

Comment: ohh sorry, yes. As it belongs to an specific namespace, I thought I couldn't get that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `x:Name` property in the XAML, and you will be able to reference it by that name from the code behind.

Comment: Thanks for your answers H.B. and slugster. Taking the opportunity, what's difference betwen x:Name and Name

Comment: @Oscar Fimbres: [`x:Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) is a XAML directive which registers a name and associates a field of your Window/UserControl with the instance it has been set on if applicable. This is useful as not all objects you can add in XAML have a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) property of their own, if an object has a `Name` you can just use that in most cases.

Comment: @Oscar: Just note that most (if not all) WPF controls that contain a `Name` property is usually mapped to `x:Name`. They typically have the [`RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.runtimenamepropertyattribute.aspx) applied which allows this mapping.